# Is there way to change runtime type in Google Colab using python

Tags: python, computer-science, google-colaboratory

[Google Colab Runtime Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1iwV.png)

Is there way to change runtime type in Google Colab using python code instead of using GUI as shown in the image.

Comment: It does not appear to be supported yet in the official github repository for google colab.
You can however automate a lot of other things, see https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

You can read the notebook.ipynb into json string. Edit it, the overwrite it or create a new notebook file.

It may be easier to download it, edit it with a text editor, then upload and open it again.

For example, a notebook.ipynb with GPU runtime will look like this

```
{
    "nbformat": 4,
    "nbformat_minor": 0,
    "metadata": {
        "colab": {...},
        "kernelspec": {
            "name": "python3",
            "display_name": "Python 3"
        },
        "accelerator": "GPU"
    },
    "cells": [...]
}
```

To change to Python 2.7, you change "name":"python2".

To change to GPU runtime, you add "accelerator": "GPU".

You can do this by hand (edit it in a text editor) or by Python (read json to dict, replace, overwrite, re-open).

Comment: My question is how to change runtime type : GPU ,TPU using Python

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: I think this addressed a perhaps common use-case (though doesn't address the question directly) where people want others who open their notebook to have it run via GPU automatically, though it would be nice to know if this has been tested to be the result for the above method.

Comment: For me this solution didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can change run time type by going

`Runtime` -> `Change run time type` -> `GPU,TPU`